# Restlet cannot process json

Tags: java, rest, restlet

This is my simple restlet code:

```
public class MailServerResource extends ServerResource {

    @Get("json")
    public String getMail() {
        return this.getRequest().getEntityAsText();
    }

    @Post("json")
    public String sendMail() {
        return this.getRequest().getEntityAsText();
    }
}
```

Now when I access this resource and pass this string:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

It throws:

```
The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method
```

[image]

Comment: try checking you json string.. use validator and reformat the json ..Try this http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes the json is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this syntax?

```
@Post("json")
public String sendMail(String json) {
    return json;
}
```

Annotated methods can contain a single argument that represents the request's entity (if any).

Nb: as a side note, the Get requests does not have a payload. This instruction has no meaning:

```
this.getRequest().getEntityAsText()
```